# How did Batman develop genius-level intellect?

Tags: dc, batman

In the DC universe (whether it's post Infinite Crisis Multiverse or New 52) Batman is not a ***metahuman***. However despite that, Batman has almost always been described as the world's greatest detective who has a ***Genius Level Intellect***.

**Has it ever been described by DC, in any comic, how Batman developed genius level intellect**?

IIRC, they talk about how he developed his other talents but they don't talk about how he developed his intellect.

For example (we learn from The Dark Knight) Ra's al Gul trained Bruce Wayne in every aspect of Ninjutsu. Similarly Batman was trained by Zatara, a stage magician to give the illusion of disappearing.

So, did Batman/Bruce Wayne receive similar training from any individual/s that helped him to develop his intellect,did he acquire genius level intellect all by himself or was he just born with it?

Comment: Isn't intellect often considered to have a strong genetic component? Why shouldn't we assume he was just born with it?

Comment: Fair Point. Added it. But has DC ever mentioned that Bruce Wayne was a child prodigy who had matchless intellect and amazing power of deductions?

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to wait for the Batman experts to answer. :)

Comment: You want a nature versus nurture argument here? Because that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: @Broklynite - because Batman used Emacs instead of Vi. *DVK throws a whole set of incendiary balloons on the fire and runs away*

Comment: @Adamant IQ is 60% genetic, but has an inverse disposition... which means that smart parents produce dumb children and vice verce hereditarily... The dominant factor in IQ though is having access to, they say books, but I'm fairly certain it is access to accurate information in whatever form it takes. The more accurate information you have as a kid (access being not that it just exists but noone is preventing you from using it) the higher your IQ is to be.

Comment: @Durakken This inverse disposition idea seems completely inconsistent with every family I've ever met. Where'd you get that?

Comment: @DCShannon It was from a Google talk thing on the subject. Keep in mind Intelligent parents often are able to provide education and such to their kids that would play more of a role in IQ than the genetics and likewise dumber parents are more likely to be broke and thus less likely to provide for their children.

Comment: @D_S Please clarify what you mean by main continuity... when most people say that they generally think modern age, but current main continuity is New52 sorta...

Comment: @Durakken - Could you link to definitive sources? That a parental phenotype would be inversely correlated with that of the offspring is a pretty strong claim.

Comment: @Adamant Nope. I couldn't. I've only seen it once and it was pretty backed up when I saw it, but I have no idea where it is, only that it was a google talks thing. I don't know what it was called and it's been a few years so I'm not even sure the video still exists.

Comment: @Durakken Thanks for highlighting that part. I was referring to the Original Multiverse as well as the New 52. Does this answer your question? Thanks again.

Comment: Not really, cuz Original would refer to pre-crisis Infinite Earths Multiverse... I suspect you mean Bronze Age post Infinite Crisis Multiverse and New 52 ^.^

Comment: Dr Kawashima's Brain Training on the Nintendo DS.

Comment: Bruce's parents, especially Thomas, were themselves wealthy and intelligent. In addition to Bruce being naturally gifted and talented, I expect his parents paid for private tuition / handed him over to Alfred, so Bruce got a very good education. That's what makes him so intelligent. He's got Nature AND Nurture.

Comment: It would be good to narrow the scope on this to a certain continuity or split this into two questions. This sort of thing is told mostly in flashbacks across several stories and writers. I know I've seen some New 52 stuff from his early training that might answer the question but it overrides plenty of pre-New 52 stuff. I also recall an old story (Detective Comics #226 according to a quick Google search) where Bruce is trained to be an expert detective as a boy and becomes Robin - yes, Robin. Limiting the scope here would help paint a better picture and invite a better answer.

Comment: obligatory "shouldn't this be moved to chat"

Comment: I met a human once. Didn't care for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Batman is the smartest human. The two immediately beneath him are Mister Terrific and Lex Luthor.

It is often overlooked that Bruce is naturally intelligent to begin with.  He went to the top colleges where he took classes in a number of areas under various faux identities.  At some point in canon, Bruce was went through CIA/NSA training, leaving after he realized it wasn't a good way to accomplish his goals.  He graduated from Yale. You can see diplomas in some issues (as shown below), but I think the whole CIA/NSA thing was stricken as possibly was the graduating from a university, but I'm not sure.

[image: Image on Bruce's presumed Diploma]

On top of that and more concretely, Bruce studied in Nanda Parbat which trained him to have an eidetic memory as well as other mental training.

In other words: He studied a lot, has an eidetic memory, and is naturally gifted. On top of all this, you have to remember he started training for this since he was ten and had the best education that money could buy.

Comment: A reference would be nice. What Batman continuity are we talking about here?

Comment: @tilley31 I agree, but references with regard to this would be spread across several comics, in the background, and referenced in issues in like maybe 1 line or picked up on from info not directly stated. Further this more or less changes every time its mentioned so its fairly worthless for sourcing. The summation is the important part... Lots of Study + learned to have an eidetic memory + Naturally gifted. Extra detail stuff is prone to changing even within the same canon universe.

Comment: I agree more references would be great, but these are good points, and that's a nice catch in the picture, so +1.

Comment: The movies don't show just how smart he is..

Comment: @EricSSH Obviously, because the Tim Burton films don't really focus on crime solving, but rather "the bad guy", where the Nolan films are so removed from Batman that he shouldnt even be considered the same character. Nolan Bruce goes most of his life wanting revenge, the Justice system didn't go his way so he thought to take things into his hands with attempted murder, but then chickened out and went soul searching where he got drawn into a cult, rebeled a little.. and then goes back home as crazy person. BvS Batman is the closest to Bronze Age Bruce. West's Batman is the most accurate overall

Comment: @Durakken Any idea what Bruce Wayne studied in Nanda Parbat? Thanks.

Comment: This answer definitely needs sources. There are several continuities and in each of them the details behind Batman's origin and training are re-written and changed countless times. I can think of a few stories off the top of my head that contradict some of the things you're saying. That isn't to say you're wrong because Lord knows comics contradict each other all the time. We just need to know what authority your answer comes from.

Comment: @D_S It changes what he learns from Nanda Parbat, but you could argue he learned all the various things and he just doesn't mention them cuz that's not what he's talking about at the time. The 1 thing I can remember his saying that he learned there (or maybe it's Dick saying he learned it from Bruce who learned it from there) The ability to slow his heart rate, meditate, and enter a near death state. There are also plenty of scenes where he's topless climbing snowy mountains. That's Nanda Parbat training.

Comment: @TheIronCheek As I mentioned earlier, even within a given canon his training changes constantly and the physical side is what we see most talked about while the mental side is usally talked about tangentially, but in the end the "actual" answer remains regardless of canon of his training. Eidetic memory + Studies alot + Naturally Gifted.

Comment: @Durakken - Just as important as your potentially right answer is how you know it's the right answer. Given that part of the OP's question is if he received training from others to develop his intellect, that answer changes depending on the continuity. Some sources show him with a college degree, others depict him bouncing from college to college for well-rounded teachings, others depict him as self-taught. Some sources describe training by experts in detection, others say experts in man-hunting, others in engineering. I'm only suggesting you explicitly state where your answer comes from.

Comment: @Durakken - If you Google "smartest characters in dc universe" or "where did batman go to college", for example, you'll get a million unsourced, conflicting answers. Asserting your answer is correct and the only correct answer does nothing to provide clarity to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This may be of interest: First the link to [DC Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Origins) notes the first origin is Detective Comics  #33 and "Batman has had his origin story retold differently several times over his many years of publication, with significant variations in continuity."

[Synopsis for "The Batman Wars Against the Dirigible of Doom"](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_33)

"Fifteen years ago, Bruce Wayne is walking home from a movie with his father Thomas Wayne and his mother. They are approached by a mugger who tries to grab his mother's necklace. Thomas Wayne shouts for the mugger to leave her alone, and menaces him. The mugger shoots Thomas Wayne dead, saying that he asked for it. Bruce's mother is horrified and calls for the police. The mugger shoots and kills her also so she'll stop screaming. The young Bruce is horrified. Several days later, he kneels next to his bed by candlelight and makes a solemn vow. He swears by the spirit of his parents to avenge their deaths, by spending the rest of his life warring on all criminals. **Years pass and Bruce Wayne prepares for this career. He becomes a master scientist, and trains his body to physical perfection**. ...... Just then a huge bat flies through the open window, like an answer to his question. Bruce Wayne declares that this is an omen, and he shall become a bat. Thus was born this weird figure of the dark... this avenger of evil... The Batman."

I've found these images that may help, where Bruce Wayne talks of "I have studied"

[image]

(I believe it is from the above story)

Another image:

[image]

Comment: You will notice that the author states `He becomes a master scientist`. But he does not explain how he became a master scientist.This is basically true for almost all Batman comics. How Batman/Bruce Wayne developed his physical prowess is vividly explained but how he developed his intellect is not that well explained.

Comment: For me, the implication is that he studied.

Comment: I've added two images I've found, where Bruce Wayne points out "I have studied, I have trained". The images are in different styles and I'm not too sure of the origin of these images, particularly the second one.