# Batman as a child -- did he show any exceptional behavior before his parents' murder?

Tags: dc, batman

Obviously, their murder was responsible for Bruce Wayne becoming Batman, a very exceptional person. My question is, was the young Bruce Wayne shown to be, prior to this event, a child prodigy or was he a normal kid?

In those days, kids who scored extremely high on academic/IQ tests were routinely "skipped" multiple grades. Was this the case with BW before his parents' death?

Comment: Supposedly he has an IQ of 192. I'm assuming he was a smart kid

Comment: @Valorum: yes, but what did we see of this or does BW's recorded history pretty much start from the time his parents were murdered?

Comment: [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/134544/58193).

Answer (score 5):

We see Bruce in his youth in [*Adventure Comics #275*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure_Comics_Vol_1_275) (1938). He shows excellent intellect and athleticism.

[image]

He's also interested in fighting crime and serving justice.

[image]

---

In *[Batman: Urban Legends #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Urban_Legends_Vol_1_8)* (2021), we see a young Bruce being read a story by his father. He shows an almost pathological obsession with preparedness, even at this formative age.

[image]

Comment: The OP asks for evidence of genius before his parents were murdered. The first example you cite is obviously from after the murder, when he is training himself.

Comment: @Pete - I would draw your attention to the first panel ***"Boys and girls, meet Bruce Wayne. His father is Doctor Wayne who has just moved into town"***

Comment: what are the red-headed characters?

Comment: @releseabe - Those are Professor Pyg's kidnapped brainwashed minions. The story revolves around Batman's flashback to his childhood because of the *villain du jour's* name

Comment: Hmm. The comic book artist seems to be really bad at drawing children. They look like adults. In most versions Bruce was only 8 years old when his parents died

Comment: @Ivobeckers - Yes, he was retconned to be much younger in later comics. In the earliest origins he looks about 10-14